# Conda Virtual Environment issues (Linux)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, virtualenv, conda

I've been trying to create a virtual environment (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, GNU/Linux 4.4.0) using Conda and am running into 2 errors:

The first has to do with setting the environment variable for CUDA support. I've tried to install 'mpiexec' to enable this option, but the issue still occurs. How can I set the env variable?

```
For Linux 64, Open MPI is built with CUDA awareness but 
this support is disabled by default.
To enable it, please set the environmental variable 
OMPI_MCA_opal_cuda_support=true before launching your MPI 
processes.
```

Secondly below, I've tried installing appdirs 1.4.3 seperately using `conda install -c conda-forge appdirs=1.4.3=py_1` to solve this issue, but I do not want to update Python to 3.7 (env only works in 3.6).

```
failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred 
while installing package 'conda-forge::appdirs-1.4.3-py_1'. 
FileNotFoundError(2, "No such file or directory:
```

Is there any way to solve this issue as well? Thank you very much!